# Force ESLint to use ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

I have my ESLint all set up and working, but I want it to throw errors whenever I don't use ES6 stuff like `let`, `const` or arrow functions (`=>`).

### .eslintrc

```
{
  "env": {
    "node": true,
    "es6": true,
    "mocha": true
  },
  "rules": {
    "semi": 2
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": 6,
    "sourceType": "script",
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "arrowFunctions": true,
      "binaryLiterals": true,
      "blockBindings": true,
      "classes": true
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, this will not throw errors for:

### main.js

```
var stars = [];
var speed = 20;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);

  // Create 1000 stars
  for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    stars.push(new Star());
  }
}
```

Comment: How is any style checker or linter supposed to know when you should or should not use arrow functions? There is a `no-var` rule though.

Comment: I wondered if that was the case really. Since Es6 lets you use Es5 things

Comment: Arrow functions don't replace normal functions.

Comment: it's not so much that "ES6 lets you use ES5 things", but more that ES6 is a superset of ES5, so that any valid ES5 program (pretty much) **is** a valid ES6 program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use `i` in your for loop so it's not an error.

You can use the `no-var` rule but it will effect everything, not only for loops.

If you would have used `i` in your for loop, then the `no-loop-func` rule is what you are looking for.

If you prefer arrow functions as callbacks you can use `prefer-arrow-callback`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [`prefer-arrow-callback` rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-arrow-callback) to enforce using arrow functions as callbacks.

Also the [`prefer-const` rule](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/prefer-const) enforces using `const` whenever possible (i.e. if the variable is never reassigned).